# Cannot install plotly on R

Tags: r, plotly

I get the following error:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Alejandro/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
       binary  source needs_compilation
plotly  4.9.3 4.9.4.1             FALSE

installing the source package ‘plotly’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/plotly_4.9.4.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3742653 bytes (3.6 MB)
downloaded 3.6 MB

* installing *source* package 'plotly' ...
** package 'plotly' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'vctrs' 0.3.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.3.6 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... asNamespace -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'plotly'
* removing 'C:/Users/Alejandro/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/plotly'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘plotly’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGi9fpb\downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Are you using RStudio?

Comment: What command are you using? It looks like you either need to a) load the binary version, or b) install RTools.

Comment: try updating the `vctrs` pacakge to version 0.3.6

Comment: I just used install.packages("plotly") and library(plotly)

Comment: I am using RStudio indeed. How do I update vctrs?